# Using the dplyr library in R to "print" the name of the non-NA columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is my data frame:

```
a <- data.frame(id=c(rep("A",2),rep("B",2)),
                x=c(rep(2,2),rep(3,2)),
                p.ABC= c(1,NA,1,1),
                p.DEF= c(NA,1,NA,NA),
                p.TAR= c(1,NA,1,1),
                p.REP= c(NA,1,1,NA),
                p.FAR= c(NA,NA,1,1))
```

I Want to create a new character column (using `mutate()` in the `dplyr` library in R), which tells (by row) the name of the columns that have a non-NA value (here the non-NA value is always 1). However, it should only search among the columns that start with "p." and it should order the names by alphabetical order and then concatenate them using the expression "_" as a separator. You can find below the desired result, under the column called "name":

```
data.frame(id=c(rep("A",2),rep("B",2)),
                x=c(rep(2,2),rep(3,2)),
                p.ABC= c(1,NA,1,1),
                p.DEF= c(NA,1,NA,NA),
                p.TAR= c(1,NA,1,1),
                p.REP= c(NA,1,1,NA),
                p.FAR= c(NA,NA,1,1),
                name=c("ABC_TAR","DEF_REP","ABC_FAR_REP_TAR","ABC_FAR_TAR"))
```

I would like to emphasize that I'm really looking for a solution using `dplyr`, as I would be able to do it without it (but it doesn't look pretty and it's slow).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`, where we reshape the data into 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, grouped by `row_number()`), `paste` the column name column 'name' values after removing the prefix part and then bind that column with the original data

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
a %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    select(-id, -x) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -rn, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
    group_by(rn) %>%
    summarise(name = str_c(str_remove(name, ".*\\."), collapse="_"), 
         .groups = 'drop') %>%
    select(-rn) %>% 
    bind_cols(a, .)
```

-output

```
# id x p.ABC p.DEF p.TAR p.REP p.FAR            name
#1  A 2     1    NA     1    NA    NA         ABC_TAR
#2  A 2    NA     1    NA     1    NA         DEF_REP
#3  B 3     1    NA     1     1     1 ABC_TAR_REP_FAR
#4  B 3     1    NA     1    NA     1     ABC_TAR_FAR
```

---

Or use `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
a %>% 
   mutate(name = pmap_chr(select(cur_data(), contains('.')), ~ {
       nm1 <- c(...)
       str_c(str_remove(names(nm1)[!is.na(nm1)], '.*\\.'), collapse="_")}))
#  id x p.ABC p.DEF p.TAR p.REP p.FAR            name
#1  A 2     1    NA     1    NA    NA         ABC_TAR
#2  A 2    NA     1    NA     1    NA         DEF_REP
#3  B 3     1    NA     1     1     1 ABC_TAR_REP_FAR
#4  B 3     1    NA     1    NA     1     ABC_TAR_FAR
```

---

Or use `apply` in `base R`

```
apply(a[-(1:2)], 1, function(x) paste(sub(".*\\.", "", 
        names(x)[!is.na(x)]), collapse="_"))
#[1] "ABC_TAR"         "DEF_REP"         "ABC_TAR_REP_FAR" "ABC_TAR_FAR"
```

Comment: Thanks! What does the expression `str_remove(name, ".*\\.")` do exactly?

Comment: @AnthonyHauser it is to match those prefix `p.`  i.e. `.*` 0 or more characters till the `.` (`.` is metacharacter to match any character so we escape) and remove it (as it was not in your expected)

Comment: Dear Arun, my code produces the desired result but there is a message that is produced and it indicates how new names are being named. I was wondering how I could suppress it or where it did come from. It usually happens when I use `pmap`.

Comment: What does `c(...)` mean?

Answer (score 4):

I think my answer may be similar to others, still I feel syntax is written in `tidyverse` pipe style so may be easier to understand.  Still someone, if feels it is copy of theirs, I will be happy to delete it.

```
a %>% mutate(name = pmap(select(cur_data(), contains('p')), 
                         ~ names(c(...))[!is.na(c(...))] %>%
                           str_remove_all(., "p.") %>%
                           paste(., collapse = '_')
                         )
             )
  id x p.ABC p.DEF p.TAR p.REP p.FAR            name
1  A 2     1    NA     1    NA    NA         ABC_TAR
2  A 2    NA     1    NA     1    NA         DEF_REP
3  B 3     1    NA     1     1     1 ABC_TAR_REP_FAR
4  B 3     1    NA     1    NA     1     ABC_TAR_FAR
```

The idea behind it is actually we can use pipes inside of map/reduce family of functions so as to obviate the necessity of writing a custom function beforehand and also creating intermediate objects inside `{}`

Comment: You are an amazing R programmer/ user. Nobody would think as such as you've already written so many lines of fabulous coding some of which quite unthinkable for me.

Comment: So are we all :)

Answer (score 3):

Using `rowwise` :

```
library(dplyr)

cols <- grep('^p\\.', names(a), value = TRUE)

a %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(name = paste0(sub('p\\.', '', 
                cols[!is.na(c_across(starts_with('p')))]), collapse = '_')) %>%
  ungroup

#  id        x p.ABC p.DEF p.TAR p.REP p.FAR name           
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>          
#1 A         2     1    NA     1    NA    NA ABC_TAR        
#2 A         2    NA     1    NA     1    NA DEF_REP        
#3 B         3     1    NA     1     1     1 ABC_TAR_REP_FAR
#4 B         3     1    NA     1    NA     1 ABC_TAR_FAR
```

Comment: Why do you need `c_across` and not `across`?

Comment: `c_across` is used when using `rowwise`.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**
Special thanks to dear @akrun for helping me improve my codes:
We just made a subtle modification to suppress a message produced by `unnest_wider`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

a %>%
  mutate(name = pmap(select(a, starts_with("p.")), ~ {nm1 <- names(c(...))[!is.na(c(...))]; 
  setNames(nm1, seq_along(nm1))})) %>%
  unnest_wider(name) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(across(8:11, ~ str_remove(., fixed("p.")))) %>%
  unite(NAME, c(8:11), sep = "_", na.rm = TRUE)

# A tibble: 4 x 8
  id        x p.ABC p.DEF p.TAR p.REP p.FAR NAME           
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>          
1 A         2     1    NA     1    NA    NA ABC_TAR        
2 A         2    NA     1    NA     1    NA DEF_REP        
3 B         3     1    NA     1     1     1 ABC_TAR_REP_FAR
4 B         3     1    NA     1    NA     1 ABC_TAR_FAR
```

Comment: It is from the `unnest_wider` as you are creating new columns based on that vector.  It creates new column names with `...1`, `..2` etc.  It is just a friendly warning

Comment: @akrun you are right. If it weren't for your teachings, I would not have been able to come up with that `pmap` syntax. I owe you as always and thank you.

Comment: You can address that issue by naming the vector `mutate(name = pmap(select(a, starts_with("p.")), ~ {nm1 <- names(c(...))[!is.na(c(...))]; setNames(nm1, seq_along(nm1))})) %>%`

Comment: @akrun thank you so much that was awesome. Here when we use `{` it is as if we are writing a body of a function with multiple expressions. Am I correct? since we added a `setNames` function separated by `;`.

Comment: yes, when we have more than one expression, we use the `{}`.  It is the same usage as in a `for` loop i.e. `for(i in 1:10) print('hello')` doesn't need a `{}` because it is a single expression

Comment: Its a great learning everytime.  I'm also trying my hands on it yet.

Comment: @AnilGoyal 100% agree with you.